# Error redirect to output stream failed while echo to file. why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
res=`echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt 2>&1`
```

/home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt: Permission denied

```
echo $res
```

EMPTY LINE

i expect the error to be stored in the variable res , why it is not getting stored and what to do for having error stored in the variable ?

Comment: You redirected the error message to `/home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt`, which isn't writable for you.

Comment: In this case the error comes from the shell, not from the command. At the same time your redirect _everything_ (both `stdout` and `stderr` of the command) to a file. Therefore, there are at least two problems with your example, and it is not clear which one you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Your error comes from the *shell*, not from the command, therefore you have to redirect the output stream of the *shell*, for example, like this:

```
$ res=$(bash -c 'echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt' 2>&1)
$ echo $res
bash: /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt: No such file or directory
```

Actually, there exists a somewhat nicer syntax for creating subshells:

```
$ res=$((echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt) 2>&1)
$ echo $res
bash: /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: res=$(bash -c 'echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt' 2>&1)

this much isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

**use bracket**

```
res=`(echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt) 2>&1`
```

**Explanation : 
you redirect data to any stream only once.**

```
res=`echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt 2>&1`
```

over here you are redirecting first "hello" to output stream and then the error to output stream which is not correct. So to tell the shell that we want to redirect the error produced from anything out of the command :

```
echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt
```

we should use parentheses to wrap the command.

Comment: `res="$( ( echo "hello" > /home/directory/folder1/xxx.txt) 2>&1 )"`, avoid old backtic if possible